# Чи можна вживати словосполучення "постійно діючий"?

Tags: росіянізм, розмовна-українська, дієприкметники

В Академічному тлумачному словнику зустрічаю вислів "постійно діюча", але в інших джерелах вказано, що вживати необхідно просто слово "постійна"

То як правильно?

[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/rada)

> *Всесвітня Рада Миру див. мир 1; Рада Безпеки ООН — основний *постійно діючий* орган ООН, на який покладено головну відповідальність за підтримання міжнародного миру й безпеки.

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53396/26485.html)

> Замість діючий у таких словосполученнях, як діючий прем’єр, діючий правопис, діюча програма, діюче законодавство, тепер у літературній мові вживають чинний прем’єр, чинний правопис, чинна програма, чинне законодавство. 
>   Невже обов’язково дослівно перекладати російською *постоянно действующая* выставка? По-українськи достатньо сказати або написати постійна виставка. 
>   У значенні “вагомий”, “ефективний”, “результативний” найчастіше виступає слово дійовий. “З турботи про рідних, про найближчих людей і починається дійова доброта людська”; дійовий вплив, дійовий засіб, дійове виховання, дійове знаряддя тощо.

Answer (score 1):

Олександр Пономарів *["Культура слова: мовностилістичні поради"](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/poshyreni-pomylky)* радить викоримтовувати просто слово ***"постійна"***

З ним погоджуються більшість мовознавців, зокрема Олена Курило, Борис Антоненко-Давидович, Юрій Шевельов, Святослав Караванський, радили й радять [усувати з тексту зайве за змістом активного дієприслівника](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieprukmetnuku-iz-zakinchennyamu-achuj,-yachuj,-uchuj,-yuchuj-vzhuvatu-chu-ni): **постійна** виставка (а не **"постійно діюча"**).